# Derivative of an integral with variable in upper bound and a term of the integrand

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I want to take the first and second derivatives of a function g(Z) which is made up of several terms, one of which is

[image: term 2]

where Z and H are our variables.

Taking the derivative of this, it seems to me that the integral would evaluate to zero in applying the upper bound according to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus; we would receive

(Z - Z) = 0, taking our solution to 0 - Z*F(0).

Am I on the right track or is there special consideration that needs to be paid to the (Z-H) term as we evaluate the derivative? Since our overall function g(Z) is in terms of Z, it seems the goal would be to eliminate H from the expression, and integrating by parts doesn't look like it will help there.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

I would say

$\displaystyle g(z) = \int_{0}^{z}(z-h)f(h)\,dh=z\int_{0}^{z}f(h)\,dh-\int_{0}^{z}hf(h)\,dh$

so $\displaystyle g'(z) = \left (z\int_{0}^{z}f(h)\,dh\right)'-\left (\int_{0}^{z}hf(h)\,dh\right )'=\cdots$

Comment: You're pulling z out of the first integral because as the upper limit of the definite integral it's treated as a constant?

Comment: @Anonymoose: The integration is not performed by the variable z, but by the variable h. So it is possible pulling z out of the first integral as a constant.
However, the expression $ \left (z\int_{0}^{z}f(h)\,dh\right)'$ it is necessary to differentiate a product.